# How to unlock bonuses for witcher gear?

Tags: the-witcher-3

What is this supposed to mean? Using this gear unless grandmaster is unlocked is useless? Is this not possible unless I find all the witcher gear schematics?
[image: ses for witcher gear]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using that gear gives you the improvements listed in the right hand panel (+24% Sign intensity....)

You don't get the bonus for using 3 or 6 pieces until the armor is upgraded to GrandMaster level - which you can only do in the Blood and Wine area.

Comment: meaning that the set is useless, by the time you get it you would have finished the game. lol

Comment: @vipin8169 No, you get the improvements listed in the right hand panel which are very useful (even vital) in themselves.

Comment: there are a lot of other equipment which gives that stats, i mean the set is useless anyway.

Comment: Actaulyl the witcher gear stats are always the best

Comment: Witcher gear is almost always better than other pieces, and because the of the great bonuses they grant to complement the play style indicated by the flavor text, they usually outperform higher-leveled pieces.

Comment: yeah true, but the thing is that the game does not let you upgrade them. say u have lvl 81 gear now, and you leveled up, now you are lvl 100, that gear is useless now.

Comment: i had Tesham Mutna armor set, started a new game+, that set is useless now. no way for me to upgrade that set